# File no longer compiles; missing packages

Tags: packages, compiling, installing, compilation-error

Recently, I've encountered errors compiling tex files using XeLaTeX in Sublime Text. I've compiled these same files earlier before without any major errors. I can't recall making any major changes to LaTeX, though I may have had performed a few OS updates. The problem seems to be that it can't find certain packages. It gives me errors along these lines:

```
LaTeX Error: File `siunitx.sty' not found. [^^I^^I^^I\allowdisplaybreaks]
```

I don't understand what's going on as the package at the following location: `/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty`. The same issue happens with other packages including: `lipsum`, `newtxmath`, `ebgaramond`, & `ebgaramond-maths`. For some reason LaTeX is having trouble locating them.

The other errors I'm get are along the lines of:

`Missing = inserted for \ifnum. [^^I^^I\newcommand]`

I figure they're related to the missing package ordeal. Does anyone know what may be causing this and/or how to fix this?

Comment: Which OS? Is `/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive` in your `TEXMF` search path (try `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMF` to see the search path)? As long as you have errors because of missing packages, other errors could be caused by this.

Comment: @Schweinebacke MacOS Mojave. kpsewhich gives me the following paths: `/Users/Username/.texlive2016/texmf-config,/Users/Username/.texlive2016/texmf-var,/Users/Username/Library/texmf,!!/opt/local/etc/texmf,!!/opt/local/var/db/texmf,!!/opt/local/share/texmf-local,!!/opt/local/share/texmf,!!/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive`

Comment: Try `texhash` (or `sudo texhash` if root rights are needed to write to `/opt/local/share/texmf-local`). After this successfully completes, `kpsewhich siunitx.sty` should find `/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty`. If so, try another LaTeX run. BTW: `.texlve2016` sounds like a very old TeX Live installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem with help from egreg. It turns out I had a MacPorts version of TeX Live installed in addition to MacTex. After I properly removed MacPorts, I was able to compile using MacTex with no further errors.

Details available here: [Fontspec compilation error with MacTeX-2018](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485747/fontspec-compilation-error-with-mactex-2018)