# Fontspec compilation error with MacTeX-2018

Tags: xetex, fontspec, mactex, compilation-error

Fontspec (and several other packages) were not working. I reinstalled MacTeX-2018, but the same errors keep coming up (see below). l3kernel & l3packages are both installed. All packages on TeX Live Utility are up to date. I'm running macOS Mojave.

Input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
TraditionalBuilder: Engine: xelatex. Invoking latexmk... done.

Errors:

/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty:26: 
Missing = inserted for \ifnum. [\RequirePackage{expl3}[2018-04-12]]
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty:27: 
Missing = inserted for \ifnum. [\@ifpackagelater{expl3}{2018-04-12}]
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty:23: 
Missing = inserted for \ifnum. [\ProvidesExplPackage]
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty:43: 
Missing = inserted for \ifnum. [\ProvidesExplPackage]

Warnings:

/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty: 
Package fontspec Warning: 
I have found the tuenc.def encoding definition file(fontspec)                
but the TU encoding is not defined by the LaTeX2e(fontspec)                
kernel; attempting to correct but you really should(fontspec)                
update to the latest version of LaTeX2e.
```

Comment: Looks as if some packages are outdated. Check the log-file if some files are loaded from local sources.

Comment: Apparently your `PATH` variable points to a MacPorts installed version of TeX Live. Remove it.

Comment: Please tell us which version numbers of `fontspec` (2019/02/12 v2.7b?), `fontspec-xetex` (2019/02/12 v2.7b?), and `tuenc.def (tuenc.def) are installed on your system. (The information in parentheses in the preceding sentence is the version information on my MacTeX2018 installation -- no MacPort, just the "straight" version.)

Comment: @egreg If I delete `/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/` it gives me the following error on compilation: `LaTeX Error: File article.cls not found.` What's the proper way to remove it?

Comment: @iteu What's the output of the terminal command `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXINPUTS`?

Comment: It was not getting its files from the TeX Live installed by MacTeX. What does `echo $PATH` return? It should have `/Library/TeX/texbin` pretended in the PATH variable.

Comment: @egreg `.:{/Users/User/.texlive2016/texmf-config,/Users/User/.texlive2016/texmf-var,/Users/User/Library/texmf,!!/opt/local/etc/texmf,!!/opt/local/var/db/texmf,!!/opt/local/share/texmf-local,!!/opt/local/share/texmf,!!/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive}/tex/{kpsewhich,generic,}//` That's after deleting `/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/`

Comment: @iteu You should remove the MacPorts TeX Live with MacPorts tools, otherwise you'll remain with TeX binaries in `/opt/local/bin`. I abandoned MacPorts several years ago.

Comment: @egreg I reinstalled macports, updated it, and ran `sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents texlive-bin`. That seemed to have fixed the problem. Thank you.